# The IO Stream abstraction and buffered implementation in the Linux Kernel

Tags: python, linux-kernel, system-calls, iostream, strace

I am reading into the linux internals and syscall's and I am getting hung up on the term `IO Stream` (which is a shame because I am an experienced programmer).

My best guess for what an *IO stream* really is, is that it's the operation of transferring data as a *sequence of bytes* from one *file abstraction* to another.

To be clear this isn't a question on the difference between buffering and streaming.

*Buffering* is an implementation.  It is used because transferring bytes from devices to memory is slow and there's no need to do it for every few bytes because:

1. context switching is expensive
2. RAM is connected directly to the CPU and even SSD (nv-RAM) still has to go through the SATA controller

I wanted to do some analysis so I looked at the [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) docs and did an `strace` on a simple `open`:

> io.open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True)
>
> Open file and return a corresponding stream. If the file cannot be opened, an IOError is raised.

Presumably for a text file, this would be the [io.TextBase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase).

The results of the `strace` are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
with open('./sample.txt') as f:
    print(f.read())
...
# returns 3 which is the first available file descriptor
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./sample.txt", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
# check it's not a directory and lseek to 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)  
read(3, "streams of screams because I've "..., 46) = 45
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
write(1, "streams of screams because I've "..., 46streams of screams because I've read too much
) = 46
close(3)
```

So the python interpreter is doing an `openat` from the current working directory because I used a *./*, on the file path.  Then some checks and `lseek` to move the *marker* to first byte in the file.

Then `read`s the file and `write`s it to *stdout*.

What confuses me here I think is that line in the python docs saying *return a corresponding stream*.

What is it about the `TextBase` class for example that makes it a **corresponding stream**?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. "corresponding stream" is a steam, operations with which "corresponds" to operations with a file on a disk. That is reading from the steam (`.read()`) corresponds (in common sence) to reading information from the file on disk, and so on.